# Show blank if customer not in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Tables**

- Customer c (Primary key  = ID)
- CustomerGroup cg (Foreign Key = CustID)

**Contents**

- Customer - ID, name
- Customer Group ID, CustID, Name

**Fields to retreive**

c.Name, cg.Name

**Problem**

I'd like to show all customers who are in a group called 'Sales' and display the 'Sales' value in cg.Name.  But then any customer who is not in a group called 'Sales', show the customer name but leave the group name 'Blank'.

**Tried**

```
SELECT c.Name, cg.Name, [NotInGroup].group
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN CustomerGroup cg on cg.CustID= c.ID
OUTER APPLY(
SELECT c2.Name, cg2.Name as [group]
FROM Customer c2
LEFT JOIN CustomerGroup cg2 on cg2.CustID= c2.ID
WHERE cg1.Name != 'Sales'
) as [NotInGroup]
WHERE cg.Name = 'Sales'
```

**Desired Result**

- Customer 1 'Sales'
- Customer 2 'Sales'
- Customer 3 ' '
- Customer 4 ' '
- Customer 5 'Sales'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem with the SQL you have now, apart from that `[NotInGroup].group` will generate an error because `GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL Server and `group` is unquoted; I suggest against using reserved (and even key) words for object names/aliases. Also, you are using a `LEFT JOIN` but referencing the column in the `WHERE`, therefore implicitly turning them into an `INNER JOIN` (guessing that might be your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a `left join`:

```
SELECT c.Name, cg.Name, 
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN
     CustomerGroups cg
     ON cg.custid = c.id AND
        cg.Name = 'Sales';
```

Note that the filtering on `Sales` goes in the `ON` clause.  This is important, unless you want a separate row for each customer and each group the customer is in.

Also, note the join conditions.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Simple solution but just was not thinking about it the right way.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Name, CASE WHEN cg.Name ='Sales' the 'Sales' else '' end
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN CustomerGroup cg on cg.ID = c.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.[Name]
       ,ISNULL(cg.[Name],'') AS GroupName
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN CustomerGroup cg ON cg.ID = c.ID AND cg.[Name] = 'Sales'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a left join and `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT c.name,
       coalesce(cg.name, '')
       FROM customer c
            LEFT JOIN customergroup cg
                      ON cg.id = c.id
                         AND cg.name = 'Sales';
```

However, I'm not sure that `customergroup.id` refrences `customer.id`. You might need to replace `cg.id` with the column actually referencing the customer.